# Is there a way to use an expression as a function's keyword?

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to use an expression as a function's keyword.

```
class A():
   def __init__(self, b):
      print(b)

a = A("test1")
a = A(b="test2")

kwrd = str("b")
a = A(kwrd="test3") #This part doesn't work but you get the idea

---------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
a = A(kwrd="test3")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwrd'
```

I want "kwrd" to be seen like the keyword "b" by the function.

Anyone has an idea? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: As a reference, please search online for `python packing / unpacking of arguments`. In the official docs, see how the `parrot` function is being called, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a dict and using the usual `**mapping` named argument expansion is probably the most convenient way:

```
kwrd = "b"
a = A(**{kwrd: "test3"})

# A(**{"b": "test3"})
# A(b="test3")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python there is a feature called "unpacking", for which you can unpack a sequence so each element is used as argument to pass to a function, and unpack a dict so that each entry is used as a keyword argument

```
# construct a dict to represent the keyword args you wanna pass
# with key being the keyword and value being the arg
your_args = {"b": "test123"}

a = A(**your_args)  # equivalent to calling A(b="test123")
```